# GTK: Set the size of a grid in C

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I want to put a grid inside a fullscreen window.
Labels, entrybars and the button are the widgets attached in the grid. I want to limit the size of grid into something like 350, 200, and place it at the center of the screen. I tried to use height-request and width-request, but they are not working.
Builder.ui looks like this:

```
<object id="grid" class="GtkGrid">
    <property name="visible">True</property>
    <property name="row-spacing">30</property>
    <property name="column-spacing">20</property>
    <property name="column-homogeneous">True</property>
    <property name="width-request">350</property>
    <property name="height-request">200</property>
```

But currently my window looks like this:
[image]
Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the grid is the immediate child of the window. In your case, changing the size of the grid is not what you want. Instead, you want to change the [alignment of the grid in its parent from `GTK_ALIGN_FILL` to `GTK_ALIGN_CENTER` in both the horizontal and vertical directions](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.20/ch30s02.html).

In Glade, you can do this near the bottom of the Common tab for the grid.

If this does not work, try putting the grid in another container, such as a GtkBox, and then make *that* the child of the window, and then make the grid's `hexpand` and `vexpand` both `TRUE` (in the same place in Glade).

Comment: Thanks! I used the first method and it worked perfectly!